# how to create an index.html while using gulp

Tags: gulp

I'm new to gulp and have built and borrowed  a gulpfile.js that builds everything but my index.html.  My assumption is that I start out with an empty destination directory, then all the stuff I create goes with that.

What is the SOP for getting an index.html there?

Comment: Where do you want the content for the index.html file to come from?

Comment: I have an index.html that includes all my javascript includes that I don't need anymore since it's all concat'd into one file now. The rest of the index.html is the same.  I might want to add some google analytics but that's about it I think.

Comment: So you want to what? Copy it from another directory?

Comment: http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/07/copying-files-from-one-folder-to-another-in-gulp-js/

Comment: yes, so is standard practice to make a new index-min.html and copy and rename it to my dist directory?

Comment: I think the best way is to use htmlreplace in gulp.  I blogged my gulp script here:   http://peterkellner.net/2014/11/11/using-gulp-build-javascript-angularjs-app/